# Installing an old version of Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

Is there any way to easily install a Foundation version, other that the latest one? Instructions for "manual" install start with

```
git clone https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template projectname
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
git clone https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template/tree/v6.1.2 projectname
```

but there is no such v6.1.2 tag

EDIT:
I have found a workaround - I run

```
git clone https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template projectname
```

And then I edit the dependencies in bower.json and proceed with the rest of the installation. At least it works for my purposes, as I mainly need the scss stuff, not the whole project. And I still have to hunt for the correct versions of scss/app.scss and scss/_settings.scss as the ones getting downloaded are for the latest version.
Would be nice if there was a fully automated way of installing a version other than the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actualy NO TAG for the Zurb-Foundation TEMPLATE project on github (https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template):
[image: Showing no tag on github]

Maybe you could switch to the actual Site project if it is what you are looking for.

EDIT:
I suggest making a ps1 or .bat script that would do the following

```
git clone https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template projectname
cd projectname
cp C://bower.json bower.json -f
npm install
bower install
```

You could also fork the template project on Github and edit it's bower.json so it's always up to date and there is no need to use the cp command

Or make a git repo of the variables you are using and do something like

```
git clone https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template projectname
git clone https://github.com/you/foundation-version foundation-version
cd projectname
cp ../foundation-version/bower.json bower.json -f
npm install
bower install
```

Comment: Thanks but the -sites repo can't be used for creating a project. At the very least you still end up with quite a bit of manual tasks to do.

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/
Just use a get method to get file complete package

Comment: The template project is a very incomplete project but I wonder why you would like to use the template instead of using the site version.

Take the index.html from the foundation template and use it with bower or another dep manager.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that the reason I'm going through all this trouble is that I need to compile the scss. What they offer for download is either css-only or something that's missing the app.scss file, making it harder for me to automate as much as possible of the process.

Comment: Are you using an IDE, you could do a batch script to automate the tasks.

I am using bower right now with a script.

git clone https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template projectname

in the file named bower.json there is the foundation-site it's using. Sadly there is no tag on the template project so you will have to overwrite the bower.json with your own to automate the process.

cd projectname
cp SomePath/bower.json bower.json -f 
npm install
bower install

Comment: And the bower.json should contains something like 

  "dependencies": {
    "foundation-sites": "^6.2.0",
    "motion-ui": "^1.2.2"
  }
}

Comment: If it's that you are looking for just let me know i'll update my answer

Comment: Yes, I guess that's good enough for my purposes. Thanks for the effort! Though, I'd still be interested in a general solution of the "install foundation -v 1.1.1" type.